# How do I harden the Noise Texture in Blender Cycles?

Tags: texturing, materials

I've been trying to make hard noise like in Blender Internal,but I'm clueless as how to do this in Blender Cycles. I want to harden the noise to create the glossy surface to the plastic like in Five Nights at Freddy's.

[image]

[image]

I've tried with a ColorRamp to replicate the image above,but it didn't work and ended up looking like the image below. And I've seen TayTay's tutorial but I didn't like how it turned out because it didn't look accurate. Can someone please help me? And to those of you who can,I'll give you a big,fat thumbs up.

[image]

```
                                                         -JeremiahTDK
```

Comment: Could you provide screenshot with this plastic material?

Comment: Have you tried turning down the detail? Then set the interpolation mode in the color ramp from linear to constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This node setup turns Cycles noise into roughly the same as Blender Internal hard noise.

[image: Hard noise in Cycles]

A comparison to how it looks in BI:
[image: BI/Cycles comparison]

Note: To get the layered noise effect (increased depth) from BI, you will need to combine several copies of this node chain, with the noise texture at various scales, added together and adjusted with a multiply node at the end. [image]

Comment: Thanks Bjørnar. Because of you showing me this,I made a perfect replica of the Noise texture. I'll release the shader on DeviantArt soon. It will be labeled "FNaF PBR Plastic" after I post it and there will be no more mass confusion for all of the FNaF fans out there who use Blender Cycles.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't get blenders noise to scale large enough for a splotchy effect. This helped me get the noise adjusted so that it would maintain shape while not becoming blurry.